# Add class to html element with PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Is there an easy way to automatically wrap any h2 element in the div class "entry-content" in another div class "entry-header"

So the end result would look something like:

```
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="entry-header">
    <h2>Some Title</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

I assume this can be done with PHP, but I'm not sure. Thanks for any input!

Comment: FWIW, I'm using this in Wordpress, and will be putting text in the h2 element from the WordPress GUI, so the PHP scripting will have to work after the item has been posted.

Comment: Does anything else go inside the divs?  If not, why not just use CSS to define how you want h2 headers to look?

Comment: Actually trying to use two separate background styles. one for the h2 and then one for the div class "entry header"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of wordpress I would probably verge towards creating a shortcode such as

```
[header]Some Title[/header]
```

I would make the shortcode take the content and wrap the given code around it.

See some documentation here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Answer (score 1):

ugly one:

```
$content = str_replace('<div class="entry-content">', '<div class="entry-content"><div class="entry-header">', $content);
$content = str_replace('</h2>', '</h2></div>', $content);
```

Comment: I agree. Same thing can be done via JavaScript replace() function, in addition.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do it in prototype ? This would be my easy solution:

```
var div = $('entry-content');

$(div).insert ({'top'  : '<div class="entry-header">'} );
$(div).insert ({'bottom'  : '</div>'} );
```

Maybe I'm missing somethig :)

Comment: how would I apply that only to the <h2>s in that div entry-content?

Comment: `var h2 = $$('entry-content h2');`

`$(h2).insert ({'before'  : '<div class="entry-header">'} );`
`$(h2).insert ({'after'  : '</div>'} );`